# How to run a python script on loop for a period of time?

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

I have a python script which takes 30 seconds to run and output the data, I require. I want the python script to continually re-run after the python script has finished for a period of 15 minutes. I have tried using Windows Task Scheduler, but it can not be configured to run programs every 30 seconds (minimum is 1 minute). I also want to the python script to re-run after the python script is finished, not in intervals of 30 seconds.

Comment: then you have to write code python itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

nest your script in a `while(True):`. At the end of your script, put a `time.sleep(15*60)`. So:

```
def main():
    # do your script 

if __name__=="__main__":
    while(True):
        main()
        time.sleep(15*60) # time in seconds, so 30 if you want 30
```

With this, just run your script with `python script.py`. Can also run it in the background if you'd prefer to free up the console.

Comment: Is _name_ mean't to be the name of my python script?

Comment: @onthepunt You can read up on what the \_\_name\_\_ variable is in python here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/name-a-special-variable-in-python but for simplicity's sake all this is saying is if you run the python script from the command line (not import it as a module), \_\_name\_\_ will be "\_\_main\_\_" which will in turn trigger the loop to run.

Comment: @GLaw1300 please include `import time` in your answer. Otherwise, it'll through an error like this 

`NameError: name 'time' is not defined`

Comment: Ok, thanks. Are you sure time.sleep(15*60) is appropriate for running the program every 30 seconds.

Comment: @onthepunt Oh haha I misread your post, for every 30 seconds it would just be time.sleep(30). I thought you wanted 15 minutes.

Comment: @onthepunt your question is confusing. Please elaborate on your question. It takes 30 seconds to run and the script ends, right? You want to wait 15 mins to re-run the script again. That's what the author of this answer understood and suggested above. Differentiate re-run of 15 mins vs 30 seconds.